# How to use v-model in Vue with Vuex and composition API?

Tags: vue.js

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>{{ counter }}</h1>
        <input type="text" v-model="counter" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { computed } from 'vue'
    import { useStore } from 'vuex'
    export default {
        setup() {
            const store = useStore()
            const counter = computed(() => store.state.counter)
            return { counter }
        },
    }
</script>
```

How to change value of counter in the store when input value changes

I am getting this error in the console:

> [ operation failed: computed value is readonly ]

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```js
...
const counter = computed({
  get: () => store.state.counter,
  set: (val) => store.commit('COUNTER_MUTATION', val)
})
...
```

https://v3.vuejs.org/api/computed-watch-api.html#computed

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input v-model="counter">

computed: {
  counter: {
    get () {
      return this.$store.state.a
    },
    set (value) {
      this.$store.commit('updateA', value)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### With composition API

When creating computed properties we can have two types, the *readonly* and a *writable* one.

To allow `v-model` to update a variable value we need a *writable computed ref*.

Example of a **readonly computed** ref:

```js
const 
   n = ref(0),
   count = computed(() => n.value);

console.log(count.value) // 0  
count.value = 2 // error
```

Example of a **writable computed** ref:

```js
const n = ref(0)
   
const count = computed({
  get: () => n.value,
  set: (val) => n.value = val
})

count.value = 2
console.log(count.value) // 2
```

So.. in summary, to use v-model with Vuex we need to use a **writable computed ref**. With composition API it would look like below:

**note:** I changed the `counter` variable with `about` so that the code makes more sense

```js
<script setup>
  import {computed} from 'vue'
  import {useStore} from 'vuex'

  const store = useStore()
  
  const about = computed({
    get: () => store.state.about,
    set: (text) => store.dispatch('setAbout', text)
  })
</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <h1>{{ about }}</h1>
        <input type="text" v-model="about" />
    </div>
</template>
```